# Specify axes position in pixels (or inches) in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add an Axes to a matplotlib figure (that I will than use to show an image).

At the moment I'm using normalized coordinates, but since the size of my figure could change, I would like to specify the position in pixels or inches to be more robust.

I tried for example:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2)) # Creates a 2"x 2" image
ax = fig.add_axes([1, 1, 1, 1], transform="figure-inches") # Creates an axes with origin at (1",1") and size 1"x 1"
```

I expect the axes to occupy the top-right quarter of my figure. However what I obtain is different, with the axes' origin in the top-right corner and the rest of the axes outside the Figure.

I tried to read [the `add_axes` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html?highlight=add_axes#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) as well as [the `Transform` tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html). However I find this part of the documentation a bit confusiong.

How can I create an Axes specifying it's size and posizion in physical units instead of normalized ones?

Comment: Did you try `fig.add_axes([.5, .5, .5, .5])` to occupy the top right quarter?  I.e. `[left, bottom, width, height]` measured from 0,0 at the bottom left to 1,1 at the top right.  `add_axes` seems to ignore the `transform=` parameter.

Comment: I want the position to be "absolute". If I change `figsize` to `2,4`, I want my axes to still have a corner 1 inch from bottom and 1 inch from the left and be 1"-by-1". If I do `add_axes([.5, .5, .5, .5])` changing `figsize` will also change the size and the position of the axes

Comment: So, you'll need to "manually" transform those coordinates from inches to figure coordinates.

Comment: Despite being a valid, althought manual, solution, shouldn't ` transform`  be there for this reason?

Comment: Feel free to file such feature request at  matplotlib's github issues.